# How to distinguish between a contract and wallet address?

Tags: etherscan, smart-contract-wallets, abi, eoa

When an address is searched, we would like to first understand if that particular address is a contract address or a wallet address. Is there a practical way of doing making that distinction?

It is not possible to distinguish from the address string itself as far as I understand. Fetching the ABI would make sense however what happens if the contract is not verified. Your suggested methods would be appreciated

Comment: There is an [asymmetry between contract addresses and EOAs in Ethereum](https://twitter.com/PaulRBerg/status/1601176488942129155).

Answer (score 1):

- The contract have codesize > 0. In solidity code you can check it by:

```
  uint32 size;
  assembly {
    size := extcodesize(_addr)
  }
  return (size > 0);
}
```

- Diagrams:

[image]

Comment: No need of doing into assembly, `_addr.code.length` works too (and has a similar cost, as it uses extcodesize under the hood)

Comment: Any alternative ways perhaps? I am simply trying to first specify if an address is a contract or not. For that, I search through the JSON Block files. Hence, I cannot foresee how I would implement Solidity code in there but recommendations are welcome